# 'chromedriver' necesita estar en el PATH pero ya esta

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Quiero enviar un mensaje a [esta pagina web](https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id=13829371) con Python.

Es por decir hacer lo siguiente pero con python :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por eso intenté el siguiente script con Selenium:

```
api_location = 'http://iphoneapp.spareroom.co.uk'
api_search_endpoint = 'flatshares'
api_details_endpoint = 'flatshares'

location = 'http://www.spareroom.co.uk'
details_endpoint = 'flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id='
def contact_room(self, room_id):
    url = '{location}/{endpoint}/{id}?format=json'.format(location=self.api_location, endpoint=self.api_details_endpoint, id=room_id)
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    # Go to your page url
    driver.get(url)
    # Get button you are going to click by its id ( also you could use find_element_by_css_selector to get element by css selector)
    button_element = driver.find_element_by_id('button id')
    button_element.click()
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\roomfinder>python test_message.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_message.py", line 21, in <module>
    contact_room(13829371)
  File "test_message.py", line 14, in contact_room
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Mientras que lo anadi en el PATH :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comprobaste que las versiones de tu navegador, Chrome, y el binario son compatibles? Por ejemplo, la ultima version de Chrome con la ultima version del binario

Comment: Una solución provisional, mientras encuentras cómo configurar correctamente el PATH, es tener el ejecutable del chromedriver en la misma carpeta que tu script python. O especificar la ruta al ejecutable como parámetro al inicializar el driver desde python.

Answer (score 0):

Evita eso usando el webdriver manager, este plugin descarga el webdriver correcto y siempre actualizado. Instalalo con `pip install webdriver_manager`, luego en tu script lo importas `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager`  y luego lo asignas a tu variable driver `driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`. Esa cosa solito descarga el driver  y lo instala en donde pueda usarlo (/tmp) y te olvidas de el para siempre ;O Más info: https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadirlo manualmente a tu PATH de Python internamente:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] = 'C:/ruta/al/binario;'+os.environ['PATH']
```

Solo no te olvides del punto y coma al final de la ruta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo hago es cargar directamente la ruta directa al ejecutable:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="c:\\program files\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Así no hay duda posible. **Importante:** cada driver tiene su propia versión de chrome. Y chrome se actualiza de la noche a la mañana prácticamente. Asegurate de que las versiones coinciden.

Answer (score -1):

¿ Si abres el CDM y escribes chromedriver te dice algo ?
En caso de que no salga nada, significa que realmente no esta detectado en PATH

En caso de que salga iniciando chromedriver puede que el problema provenga de otro sitio.

En cualquier caso, hay dos cosas que podrías probar a ver si resuelven tu problema, el primero, incluye chromedriver en el mismo directorio que tu script de python (y reinicia el IDE para ver si funciona)

Otra opción, sería cambiar la línea driver = webdriver.Chrome() y añadir entre los paréntesis la ruta a donde tienes guardado el chromedriver